# If $\mu(B_n) \to 1$ then $\int_{B_n} f \mathrm d \mu \to \int_{X} f \mathrm d \mu$

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to prove this convergence result. Could you please have a check on my attempt?

> Let $(X, \mu)$ be a probability space and $f:X \to \mathbb R$ such that $f \in L_1 (\mu)$. Assume there is a sequence $(B_n)$ of measurable sets such that $\mu(B_n) \to 1$. Then
> $$
> \int_{B_n} f \mathrm d \mu \to \int_{X} f \mathrm d \mu.
> $$

**Proof:** Because $(1_{B_n} f)_n$ does not necessarily converges to $f$ $\mu$-a.e., we are unable to apply [dominated convergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space). It suffices to prove that
$$
\int_{B^c_n} f \mathrm d \mu \to 0.
$$

We need the following lemma whose proof is given at the end.

> **Lemma:** For each $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta >0$ such that if $\mu (B) < \delta$ then $\int_{B} |f| \mathrm d \mu < \varepsilon$.

- Given $\varepsilon >0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that $\int_{B} |f| \mathrm d \mu < \varepsilon$ for all $\mu(B) <\delta$ by our **Lemma**.
- Given $\delta >0$, there is $N >0$ such that $\mu(B_n^c) < \delta$ for all $n>N$.

It follows that for each $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N>0$ such that $\int_{B^c_n} |f| \mathrm d \mu <\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$. Notice that $|\int_{B^c_n} f \mathrm d \mu| \le \int_{B^c_n} |f| \mathrm d \mu$. This completes the proof.

---

**Proof of the lemma:**  We have $f \in L_1 (\mu)$ implies $|f| \in L_1 (\mu)$, so there is a simple function $0 \le g \le |f|$ such that
$$
\int_X (|f| -g) \mathrm d \mu < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
$$

We assume $g$ has a form
$$
g = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i 1_{A_i}
$$
where $a_i \ge 0$ for $i = 1, \ldots, m$ and $(A_i)_{i=1}^m$ is pairwise disjoint sequence of measurable sets. We have
$$
\int_B g \mathrm d \mu = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i \mu (A_i \cap B)  \le \mu(B) \sum_{i=1}^m a_i.
$$

If $\mu(B) \le \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2 \sum_{i=1}^m a_i}$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\int_B |f| \mathrm d \mu &= \int_B (|f| - g) \mathrm d \mu +\int_B g \mathrm d \mu \\
&\le \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \\
&= \varepsilon.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Looks fine to me. Btw, the lemma you used is the absolute continuity property of integrals.

Comment: Another way is that if you first prove it for nonnegative functions then you can apply the result to the nonnegative function $|f|-f$.  A simple way to prove it for nonnegative functions $g(x)\geq 0$ is to truncate by $g_m(x)=\min[g(x),m]$ so $$\int_X gd\mu \geq \int_{B_n}gd\mu\geq \int_{B_n}g_md\mu \overset{n}{\rightarrow} \int_X g_md\mu$$