# Let $E$ be a Banach space and $p \in (1, \infty)$. Is $L_{p}(X, \mu, E)$ uniformly convex?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $E$ a Banach space, and $f, g \in L_{p}(X, \mu, E)$. Here we use the [Bochner integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space?noredirect=1&lq=1). If $E = \mathbb R$, then

- $$
  \left\|\frac{f+g}{2}\right\|_{L_{p}}^{p}+\left\|\frac{f-g}{2}\right\|_{L_{p}}^{p} \leq \frac{1}{2}\left(\|f\|_{L_{p}}^{p}+\|g\|_{L_{p}}^{p}\right) \quad \forall 2 \leq p<+\infty,
  $$
- $$
  \left\|\frac{f+g}{2}\right\|_{L^{p}}^{q}+\left\|\frac{f-g}{2}\right\|_{L^{p}}^{q} \leq\left(\frac{1}{2}\|f\|_{L_{p}}^{p}+\frac{1}{2}\|g\|_{L_{p}}^{p}\right)^{q/p} \quad \forall 1<p<2.
  $$
  where
  $$
  \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1.
  $$

---

Above are [Clarkson's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarkson%27s_inequalities) that help establish the uniform convexity of $L_{p}(X, \mu, \mathbb R)$ for $p \in (1, \infty)$.

> For $p \in (1, \infty)$, I would like to ask if $L_{p}(X, \mu, E)$ is proved to be uniformly convex given a general Banach (or Hilbert) space $E$.

Comment: What if $E$ has bad geometry,  and $X=\{pt\}$ is a singleton,?

Comment: @Aweygan Of course we can impose that $\dim E > 1$ to avoid the trivial case. To be honest, I know nothing about the geometry of Banach spaces :(

Comment: My apologies for being unclear.  By "$E$ has bad geometry" I meant "$E$ is not-uniformly convex," which is by no means standard notation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true.  If $E$ is $\mathbb R^2$ with the $\infty$-norm, $X=\{x\}$ is a one-point space, and $\mu$ is the counting measure on $X$, then $L_p(X,\mu,E)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $E$, which is not uniformly convex.

Comment: Could it be true if we impose a natural condition that $E$ is uniformly convex?