# Construct conditional expectation for $\mathbb C^n$-valued random variables

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(X, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $\mathbb K \in \{\mathbb R, \mathbb C\}$, and $i$ the imaginary unit. Below is the **Corollary 2.12** from Amann's *Analysis III*.

> **Corollary 2.12**
>
> - (i) $f=(f_1, \ldots, f_n) \in L_1(X, \mathcal F, \mu, \mathbb K^n)$ if and only $f_j \in L_1(X, \mathcal F, \mu, \mathbb K)$ for all $j$. In this case,
>   $$
>   \int_X f \mathrm d \mu = \left ( \int_X f_1 \mathrm d \mu, \ldots, \int_X f_n \mathrm d \mu \right ).
>   $$
> - (ii) Suppose $g, h:X \to \mathbb R$ and define $f:=g+ih$. Then $f\in L_1(X, \mathcal F, \mu, \mathbb C)$ if and only if $g,h \in L_1(X, \mathcal F, \mu, \mathbb R)$. In this case,
>   $$
>   \int_X f \mathrm d \mu = \int_X g \mathrm d \mu + i \int_X h \mathrm d \mu  .
>   $$
> - (iii) $f \in L_1(X, \mathcal F, \mu, \mathbb R)$ if and only if $f^+, f^- \in L_1(X, \mathcal F, \mu, \mathbb R_{\ge 0})$ where $f^+, f^-$ are the positive and negative parts of $f$ respectively. In this case,
>   $$
>   \int_X f \mathrm d \mu = \int_X f^+ \mathrm d \mu - \int_X f^- \mathrm d \mu \quad \text{and} \quad \int_X |f| \mathrm d \mu = \int_X f^+ \mathrm d \mu + \int_X f^- \mathrm d \mu.
>   $$

Now we assume $\mu$ is a probability measure, $f = (f_1, \ldots, f_n) \in L_1(X, \mathcal F, \mu, \mathbb K^n)$, and $\mathcal G$ a sub $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal F$. My goal is to apply **Corollary 2.12** to define the **conditional expectation** $\mathbb E (f|\mathcal G)$, i.e.,

- $\mathbb E (f|\mathcal G) \in L_1(X, \mathcal G, \mu, \mathbb K^n)$, and
- $$\int_A f \mathrm d \mu = \int_A \mathbb E (f|\mathcal G) \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall A \in \mathcal G.$$

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

1. Uniqueness. It follows from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4546113/bochner-integral-is-f-g-mu-a-e-if-their-integrals-are-equal-on-every-meas/4546566#4546566) result.
2. Existence.

> a. Let $\mathbb K= \mathbb C$ and $n=1$.

We decompose $f = g +ih$ where $g,h:X \to \mathbb R$. By **Corollary 2.12 (ii)**, $g,h \in L_1(X, \mathcal F, \mu, \mathbb R)$. Decompose $g = g^+ - g^-$. By **Corollary 2.12 (iii)**, $g^+, g^- \in L_1(X, \mathcal F, \mu, \mathbb R_{\ge 0})$. We define a measure $\nu^+ : \mathcal G \to [0, \infty]$ by
$$
\nu^+ (A ) := \int_A g^+ \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall A \in \mathcal G.
$$

Because $g^+$ is $\mu$-integrable, we get $\nu^+$ is a finite measure. Clearly, $\nu^+ \ll \mu_{\restriction \mathcal G}$. By [Radon–Nikodym theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538795/a-proof-of-radon-nikodym-theorem), there is $\mathbb E (g^+|\mathcal G) \in L_0(X, \mathcal G, \mu, [0, \infty])$ such that
$$
\nu^+ (A ) = \int_A \mathbb E (g^+|\mathcal G) \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall A \in \mathcal G.
$$

Because $\nu^+$ is finite, $\mathbb E (g^+|\mathcal G) \in L_1 (X, \mathcal G, \mu, \mathbb R_{\ge 0})$. We define $\mathbb E (g^-|\mathcal G)$ similarly. Let
$$
\mathbb E (g|\mathcal G)  := \mathbb E (g^+|\mathcal G) -\mathbb E (g^-|\mathcal G).
$$

Clearly,

- $\mathbb E (g|\mathcal G)  \in L_1 (X, \mathcal G, \mu, \mathbb R)$, and
- $$
  \int_A g \mathrm d \mu = \int_A \mathbb E (g|\mathcal G) \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall A \in \mathcal G.
  $$

We define $\mathbb E (h|\mathcal G)$ similarly. Let
$$
\mathbb E (f|\mathcal G)  := \mathbb E (g|\mathcal G) +i\mathbb E (h|\mathcal G).
$$

By **Corollary 2.12 (ii)**,

- $\mathbb E (f|\mathcal G)  \in L_1 (X, \mathcal G, \mu, \mathbb C)$, and
- $$
  \int_A \mathbb E (f|\mathcal G) \mathrm d \mu = \int_A \mathbb E (g|\mathcal G) \mathrm d \mu + i \int_A \mathbb E (h|\mathcal G) \mathrm d \mu = \int_A g \mathrm d \mu + i\int_A h \mathrm d \mu = \int_A f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall A \in \mathcal G.
  $$

> b. Let $\mathbb K= \mathbb C$.

By **Corollary 2.12 (i)**, $f_j \in L_1(X, \mathcal F, \mu, \mathbb K)$ for all $j$. The existence of $\mathbb E (f_j|\mathcal G)$ is then guaranteed by part a. above. Let
$$
\mathbb E (f|\mathcal G) := \big ( \mathbb E (f_1|\mathcal G), \ldots, \mathbb E (f_n|\mathcal G) \big ).
$$

By **Corollary 2.12 (i)**,

- $\mathbb E (f|\mathcal G)  \in L_1 (X, \mathcal G, \mu, \mathbb C^n)$, and
- $$
  \int_A \mathbb E (f|\mathcal G) \mathrm d \mu = \left ( \int_A \mathbb E (f_1|\mathcal G) \mathrm d \mu, \ldots, \int_A \mathbb E (f_1|\mathcal G) \mathrm d \mu \right ) = \left ( \int_A f_1 \mathrm d \mu, \ldots, \int_A f_n \mathrm d \mu \right ) = \int_A f \mathrm d \mu.
  $$

> c. Let $\mathbb K= \mathbb R$.

We consider $\mathbb R^n$ as a *closed* subspace of $\mathbb C^n$. Then apply b. to get $\mathbb E (f|\mathcal G)  \in L_1 (X, \mathcal G, \mu, \mathbb C^n)$. Notice that $f$ takes values in $\mathbb R^n$ *everywhere*. Then $\mathbb E (f|\mathcal G)$ takes values in $\mathbb R^n$ almost everywhere by [Theorem 1.4.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4547251/368425) from Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.

Comment: By Corollary 2.12, all we know about the integrability of an $\mathbb R$-valued function carries over to the real and imaginary parts of every component of your $\mathbb C^n$-valued function. If we know how to define a conditional expectation for the $\mathbb R$-valued function we get the rest for free. I really don't understand what one should check here exactly ? You seem to overthink it by far.

Comment: @KurtG. You are right! I just wanted to write it down clearly...