# If $\int f \mathrm d \mu$ exists and $\int g \mathrm d \mu$ is finite, then $\int (f+g) \mathrm d \mu = \int f \mathrm d \mu + \int g \mathrm d \mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal X, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $f, g:X \to \mathbb R \cup \{\pm \infty\}$  [$\mu$-measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space).

- We say that $\int f \mathrm d \mu$ **exists** if at least $\int f^+ \mathrm d \mu < +\infty$ or $\int f^- \mathrm d \mu < +\infty$. In this case,
  $$
  \int f \mathrm d \mu := \int f^+ \mathrm d \mu - \int f^- \mathrm d \mu \in \mathbb R \cup \{\pm \infty\}.
  $$
- We say that $\int f \mathrm d \mu$ is **finite** if $\int f^+ \mathrm d \mu < +\infty$ and $\int f^- \mathrm d \mu < +\infty$. In this case, $\int f \mathrm d \mu \in \mathbb R$.

We adopt the convention that $a + (\pm\infty) = (\pm\infty)$ for all $a \in \mathbb R$. I'm trying to prove the following statement, i.e.,

> **Theorem** If $\int f \mathrm d \mu$ exists and $\int g \mathrm d \mu$ is finite, then $\int (f+g) \mathrm d \mu$ exists and
> $$
> \int (f+g) \mathrm d \mu = \int f \mathrm d \mu + \int g \mathrm d \mu.
> $$

In below attempt, I'm stuck at proving $\int (f+g)^- \mathrm d \mu = +\infty$. Could you elaborate on my difficulty?

---

**Proof:** WLOG, we assume $\int f^+ \mathrm d \mu < \infty$. We have $(f+g)^+ \le f^+ + g^+$, so
$$
\int (f+g)^+ \mathrm d \mu \le \int (f^+ + g^+) \mathrm d \mu = \int f^+ \mathrm d \mu + \int g^+ \mathrm d \mu < +\infty.
$$

As such, $\int (f+g) \mathrm d \mu$ exists. If $\int f^- \mathrm d \mu <+ \infty$, the claim follows from the linearity of integral. Now we consider the case $\int f^- \mathrm d \mu =+ \infty$. Then $\int f \mathrm d \mu =- \infty$. It suffices to prove that $\int (f+g)^- \mathrm d \mu = +\infty$.

Comment: I think you'll need to go to the definition of $\int f\, d\mu = a$ and "$\int f\, d\mu = \infty$" for non-negative $f$.

Comment: @aschepler It seems I have found the proof that $\int (f+g)^- \mathrm d \mu = +\infty$. Could you have a check on my below answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my proof that $\int (f+g)^- \mathrm d \mu = +\infty$.

---

We have
$$
f^-=(-f)^+ = ((-f-g)+g)^+ \le (-f-g)^+ + g^+=(f+g)^-+g^+.
$$

It follows that
$$
\begin{align}
\int f^- \mathrm d \mu &\le \int ((f+g)^- + g^+) \mathrm d \mu \\
&\overset{(\star)}{=} \int (f+g)^- \mathrm d \mu + \int g^+ \mathrm d \mu.
\end{align}
$$

Here $(\star)$ is because $(f+g)^-$ and  $g^+$ are non-negative. Because $\int g^+ \mathrm d \mu <+\infty$, we can subtract it from both sides of  $\int f^- \mathrm d \mu \le \int (f+g)^- \mathrm d \mu + \int g^+ \mathrm d \mu$. Then we  get
$$
\int (f+g)^- \mathrm d \mu \ge \int f^- \mathrm d \mu - \int g^+ \mathrm d \mu = +\infty -\int g^+ \mathrm d \mu = +\infty.
$$

This completes the proof.