# If $\int f^+ \mathrm d \mu$ and $\int g^+ \mathrm d \mu$ are finite, then $\int (f+g) \mathrm d \mu = \int f \mathrm d \mu + \int g \mathrm d \mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal X, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $f, g:X \to \mathbb R \cup \{\pm \infty\}$  [$\mu$-measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space), i.e., they are $\mu$-a.e. pointiwse limits of some sequences of [$\mu$-simple functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space).

- We say that $\int f \mathrm d \mu$ **exists** if at least $\int f^+ \mathrm d \mu < +\infty$ or $\int f^- \mathrm d \mu < +\infty$. In this case,
  $$
  \int f \mathrm d \mu := \int f^+ \mathrm d \mu - \int f^- \mathrm d \mu \in \mathbb R \cup \{\pm \infty\}.
  $$
- We say that $\int f \mathrm d \mu$ is **finite** if $\int f \mathrm d \mu$ exists and $\int f \mathrm d \mu \in \mathbb R$.

We adopt the convention that for all $a \in \mathbb R$,

- $a + (+\infty) = (+\infty) + a = +\infty$,
- $a + (-\infty) = (-\infty) + a = -\infty$,
- $(-\infty) + (-\infty) = -\infty$, and
- $(+\infty) + (+\infty) = +\infty$.

Then we have

> [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4599701/if-int-f-mathrm-d-mu-exists-and-int-g-mathrm-d-mu-is-finite-then-in/4599887#4599887) If $\int f \mathrm d \mu$ exists and $\int g \mathrm d \mu$ is finite, then $\int (f+g) \mathrm d \mu$ exists and
> $$
> \int (f+g) \mathrm d \mu = \int f \mathrm d \mu + \int g \mathrm d \mu.
> $$

In order to justify *Step 2* in the proof of *Theorem 3.2* in the paper [Existence and stability results in the $L^1$ theory of optimal transportation](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Esaito/data/emd/ambrosio-pratelli.pdf) by Ambrosio/Pratelli, I come across below result, i.e.,

> **Theorem** If $\int f^+ \mathrm d \mu < +\infty$ and $\int g^+ \mathrm d \mu < +\infty$, then $\int (f+g) \mathrm d \mu$ exists and
> $$
> \int (f+g) \mathrm d \mu = \int f \mathrm d \mu + \int g \mathrm d \mu.
> $$

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

**Proof** Clearly, $\int f \mathrm d \mu$ and $\int g \mathrm d \mu$ exist. Moreover, $\{\int f \mathrm d \mu, \int g \mathrm d \mu\} \subset \mathbb R \cup \{-\infty\}$ and thus $\int f \mathrm d \mu+ \int g \mathrm d \mu \in \mathbb R \cup \{-\infty\}$. We have $(f+g)^+ \le f^+ + g^+$, so
$$
\int (f+g)^+ \mathrm d \mu \le \int (f^+ + g^+) \mathrm d \mu \overset{(\star)}{=} \int f^+ \mathrm d \mu + \int g^+ \mathrm d \mu < +\infty.
$$

Here $(\star)$ is becasue $f^+$ and $g^+$ are non-negative. As such, $\int (f+g) \mathrm d \mu$ exists. Moreover, $\int (f+g) \mathrm d \mu \in \mathbb R \cup \{-\infty\}$.

1. If $\int f^- \mathrm d \mu < +\infty$ then $\int f \mathrm d \mu$ is finite. The claim then follows from **Lemma**. Similarly, the claim holds if $\int g^- \mathrm d \mu < +\infty$.
2. Now we consider the case $\int f^- \mathrm d \mu = \int g^- \mathrm d \mu = +\infty$. In this case, $\int f \mathrm d \mu + \int g \mathrm d \mu = -\infty$. It suffices to prove $\int (f+g)^- \mathrm d \mu = +\infty$. We have
   $$
   f^-=(-f)^+ = ((-f-g)+g)^+ \le (-f-g)^+ + g^+=(f+g)^-+g^+.
   $$
   It follows that
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \int f^- \mathrm d \mu &\le \int ((f+g)^- + g^+) \mathrm d \mu \\
   &\overset{(\star\star)}{=} \int (f+g)^- \mathrm d \mu + \int g^+ \mathrm d \mu.
   \end{align}
   $$
   Here $(\star\star)$ is because $(f+g)^-$ and  $g^+$ are non-negative. Because $\int g^+ \mathrm d \mu <+\infty$, we can subtract it from both sides of  $\int f^- \mathrm d \mu \le \int (f+g)^- \mathrm d \mu + \int g^+ \mathrm d \mu$. Then we  get
   $$
   \int (f+g)^- \mathrm d \mu \ge \int f^- \mathrm d \mu - \int g^+ \mathrm d \mu = +\infty -\int g^+ \mathrm d \mu = +\infty.
   $$

This completes the proof.

Comment: The only concern here would be an expression of the form $\infty-\infty$, which is not defined. But given that $\int f^+\ \mathsf d\mu$ and $\int g^+\ \mathsf d\mu$ are finite, this cannot occur.

Comment: "Here $(\star)$ is becasue $f^+$ and $g^+$ are non-negative." Huh? Is this supposed to *mean* something? Is there some reason you like to put stars over equalities between positive real values?

Comment: @PaulSinclair $(\star)$ and $(\star\star)$ are just a way I use to tag equalities/inequalities...

Comment: I see - you are saying that the equality holds because $f^+$ and $g^+$ are non-negative. Well, obviously I suggest you reword it a bit (say "$(\star)$ *holds* because ..."). As is, it sounds like $\overset{(\star)}=$ is some sort of special notation.