# A characterization of convergence in the metric space $(L^0 (X), \rho)$ of $\mu$-measurable functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, measurable-functions

Below we use [Bochner measurability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function) and [Bochner integral](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral). Let

- $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a *complete finite* measure space,
- $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space,
- $S (X)$ the space of $\mu$-simple functions from $X$ to $E$, and
- $L^0 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-measurable functions from $X$ to $E$.
- $L^1 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-integrable functions from $X$ to $E$.

We define
$$
\rho (f, g) := \int_X \min\{|f-g|, 1\} \, \mathrm d \mu
\quad \forall f, g \in L^0 (X).
$$

Then $\rho$ is a [pseudometric](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pseudometric_space) on $L^0 (X)$ such that $\rho (f, g) = 0$ IFF $f=g$ a.e. I already [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753822/the-metric-space-l0-x-rho-of-mu-measurable-functions-is-complete) that $S (X)$ is dense in $L^0 (X)$ and that $L^0(X)$ is complete. I would like to verify below statement found in [this](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convergence_in_measure#Properties) Wikipedia page, i.e.,

> $\left(f_n\right)$ converges to $f$ in $(L^0 (X), \rho)$ IFF every subsequence has in turn a further subsequence that converges to $f$ a.e.

Could you have a check on my below attempt? Thank you so much for your help!

---

1. $\implies$

Let $f_n, f \in L^0 (X)$ such that $\rho(f_n, f) \to 0$. In particular, $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. For each $k \in \mathbb N$ there is $j_k \in \mathbb N$ such that
$$
\rho (f_n, f_m) \le 2^{-2k}
\quad \forall n,m \ge j_k.
$$

WLOG, we can assume $(j_k)$ is strictly increasing in $k$. Let $g_k := f_{j_k}$. Then
$$
\rho (g_n, g_m) \le 2^{-2n}
\quad \forall m \ge n.
$$

Let
$$
B_n := \{x \in X : 2^{-n} \le |g_{n+1} (x) - g_n (x)|\}.
$$

Because $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ is *complete*, $B_n \in \mathcal A$. We have
$$
2^{-n} \mu(B_n) = \int_{B_n} 2^{-n} \, \mathrm d \mu \le \int_{B_n} \min \{|g_{n+1} - g_n |, 1\} \, \mathrm d \mu \le \rho (g_{n+1}, g_n) \le 2^{-2n}.
$$

Then $\mu(B_n) \le 2^{-n}$. Let $A_n := \bigcup_k B_{n+k}$. Then $\mu(A_n) \le2^{-n+1}$. Then $A := \bigcap_n A_n$ is a $\mu$-null set. If $x \in A_n^c = \bigcap_k B_{n+k}^c$, then
$$
|g_{m+1} (x) - g_m (x)| < 2^{-m}
\quad \forall m \ge n
$$

By Weierstrass [criterion](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Weierstrass_M-test#Generalization), the series
$$
g_0 + \sum_m (g_{m+1} - g_m)
$$
on $A_n^c$ converges uniformly in $E$. Then
$$
g(x) :=
\begin{cases}
\lim_m  g_m (x) &\text{if} \quad x \in A^c,\\
0 &\text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$
is well-defined. The a.e. limit of a sequence of $\mu$-measurable functions [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507762/generalize-a-theorem-about-the-mu-measurability-of-a-mu-a-e-limit-of-a-se) again $\mu$-measurable. So $g \in L^0(X)$. Clearly,

- $f_{j_m} \xrightarrow{m \to \infty} g$ a.e.
- for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $\mu(A_n) \le2^{-n+1} < \varepsilon$ and thus $(f_{j_m})$  converges uniformly to $g$ on $A_n^c$.

By dominated convergence [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space), $\min\{|f_{j_m} - g|, 1\} \xrightarrow{m \to \infty} 0$ in $L^1(X)$ and thus $\rho (f_{j_m}, g) \xrightarrow{m \to \infty} 0$. Then $g =f$ a.e.

2. $\impliedby$

Let $f_n, f \in L^0(X)$. Let $(f_{n_k})$ be an *arbitrary* subsequence of $(f_n)$. Let $g_k := f_{n_k}$. By our hypothesis, $(g_k)$ has a subsequence $(g_{k_m})$ such that $g_{k_m} \xrightarrow{m \to \infty} f$ a.e. By dominated convergence [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space), $\min\{|g_{k_m} - f|, 1\} \xrightarrow{m \to \infty} 0$ in $L^1(X)$ and thus $\rho (f_{k_m}, f) \xrightarrow{m \to \infty} 0$. To sum up, any subsequence of $(f_n)$ has a further subsequence that converges to $f$ in $(L^0 (X), \rho)$. [Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397978/every-subsequence-of-x-n-has-a-further-subsequence-which-converges-to-x-the) $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ in $(L^0 (X), \rho)$.